# Postgres function make_interval(hours => numeric) does not exist

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq

I am trying to get a true or false value from a linq statement where I want to check if the timestamp of an object is not older than one day

```
       return await dbContext.PasswordResetTokens
            .Where(token => token.CreatedOn.AddHours(24) > DateTime.UtcNow) // is still valid (created in no longer than one day ago)
            .AnyAsync(token => token.Id == tokenId);
```

The expected result would be a true or false value.

Comment: Your example code will only grab the Tokens where the `CreatedOn` property is less than one day old. Do you need all the tokens + a true/false value for `valid` or do you need a list of only the tokens which are still `valid`?

Comment: I get all tokes which are less than one day old. I get a tokenId and any anyAsync checks if this token is part of this.

Comment: In my answer I did not use async, but you can change it to be async, and it should work @Christoph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works... Maybe a Postgres bug

var returnToken = await dbContext.PasswordResetTokens
                .Where(token => token.Id == tokenId).SingleOrDefaultAsync(); // is still valid (created in no longer than one day ago)

```
       return returnToken.CreatedOn.AddHours(24) > DateTime.UtcNow ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return dbContext.PasswordResetTokens
        .Any(token => token.Id == tokenId && token.CreatedOn.AddHours(24) > DateTime.UtcNow);
```

try it like that

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say token.CreatedOn
try it now

Comment: is CreatedOn of type DateTime?

Answer (score 0):

The following will return one true/false value for a passed `tokenId`. First, it finds the token in the list, then checked the `CreatedOn` property for less than a day old. If the statement is true, `true` is returned; else `false`

```
return await dbContext.PasswordResetTokens
                      .Find(token => token.Id == tokenId).CreatedOn.AddHours(24) > DateTime.UtcNow 
                      ? true : false;
```